# Print Size of args[] array - out of bounds exception error

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, args

I understand why an outofbounds error is thrown, but not why it is in this case.

In the course text book, some exercises include writing code to "print out its' command line argument" and "add its two command line arguements"

The two codes I've written are:

```
public class AddToCommandLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    System.out.println(x+y);
    }
```

And

```
public class AddToCommandLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    System.out.println(x+1);
    }
}
```

For both, I get the same "Exception in thread "main"j ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at AddToCommandLine.main(AddToCommandLine.java:4)"

I can't see why.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you are not passing any command line argument to this

Comment: How are you executing your program? How are you passing the parameters?

Comment: You should give command line arguements when you run the program

Comment: I had been using (or trying) to use Eclipse... very stupid! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just run your program without passing any arguments, then the size of args[] will be 0. Here you are trying to access [0] i.e, first element and [1] i.e, second element. Hence the exception.

I suggest you write something like this,

```
public class AddToCommandLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        if(args != null && args.length == 2)
        {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            System.out.println(x+y);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong number of command line arguments. This program require 2 arguments");
    }
}
```

You need to pass argument with java command as

```
java AddToCommandLine 1 2
```

and if you want to run from some IDE, then you have to go to run configurations and add arguments there.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass anything to the program as cmd line arguments, then the size of `args[]` will be `0`. Here you are trying to access `[0]` i.e, first element and `[1]` i.e, second element. Hence the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass argument with `java` command as

```
java AddToCommandLine 1 2
```

where `AddToCommandLine` is class name and `1` is `args[0]` and `2` is `args[1]`

you are not passing any argument as of now, i think

Answer (score 1):

Here is detail read up of what [command line arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) are

I suggest you write something like this,

```
public class AddToCommandLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        if(args != null && args.length == 2)
        {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            System.out.println(x+y);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong number of command line arguments. This program require 2 arguments");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run your program like

`java AddToCommandLine 5 4`